# What type of pedals are these?

Tags: pedals

My brother bought a second hand bike. He’s now looking to buy shoes. But we are uncertain what type of cleats he needs.

Is there some sort of guide on how to identify the pedals?

[image: Bottom of the pedal]

[image: Top of the pedal]

[image: Front of the pedal]

Comment: The shallow "V" shape at the nose of the pedal looks like a [Look road design](https://www.lookcycle.com/us-en/products/pedals/road?), but I haven't been able to identify the exact pedal model.  Shimano SPD-SL pedals have a nose with a more complex shape that looks curved.

Comment: A shot of the back of the pedal with the branding would be helpful

Comment: Do you have the matching cleat?  A photo of that could help.  Right now it could be a Look Delta, but can't be sure.

Comment: Also consider that if you don't have the shoes and cleats already the pedals are only part of the cost.  Changing pedals is straightforward.   These will definitely be for 3 bolt road cleats.

Comment: @Criggie They don’t have the cleats. It says they need to know what pedals these are in order for them to go buy cleats.

Comment: How about asking the seller?

Comment: I'm fairly certain these are Look Delta pattern pedals and if that SPD tool fitting down there is kind of a dull gray plastic, I think that's a tell they're Wellgo. They probably also have some kind of model number stamping somewhere that you could just google.

Answer (score 4):

They are road pedals made by XLC parts.

https://www.xlc-parts.com/en/road/bike-parts/pedals/

> At XLC you can choose between clip-in pedals based on the SPS or Look system.

You should be able work out which system that pedal is using from the part number and get the appropriate set of cleats.

Probably either Look Delta or Look Keo.

Comment: I suspect the “SPS” is actually a typo and should be “SPD”, which would be Shimano’s MTB system which uses small metal cleats. Obviously OP has a road bike system. Now the real question is if OP needs Look Delta or Look KEO cleats.

Answer (score 3):

I found an Amazon France listing at https://www.amazon.fr/XLC-Road-LOOK-System-Hipac-PD-S09einseitig-schwarz/dp/B002YEB39M

that shows cleats but doesn't name them.  To my eye they seem to be Look Delta but its not a great photo.

[image]

From above the general outline is similar - they have to match the same three-hole bolt pattern.
[image]

But Keo are much more rounded in the corners, whereas Delta are pointier, almost "horned"

[image]

---

Personally I'd inspect the pedals for wear and play, and if they're not great then buy new pedals based on a newer format, whether that be keo, or 2 bolt MTB, or even flat pedals.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say those are commonly called "road pedals". They are a subset of what are called "clipless pedals." There are corresponding [road shoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycling_shoe#Road) that fit.

From what I see in the US, there's pretty much just two major varieties of clipless pedals and cycling shoes. They're either road pedals and shoes or mountain bike pedals and shoes. I have both and from your picture would say it's clear those are road pedals.

By the way, I've found the word clipless to be a bit confusing at first, because I feel like you "clip in" to them. However, there's legacy reasoning to it as the type of clip used earlier on was more like a toe-clip.

Comment: _"...was more like a toe-clip"_ -- well, it wasn't "like" a toe-clip. It _was_ a toe-clip, i.e. a fabric, metal, or plastic basket that physically went around the toe of one's shoe. "Toe-clip" was literally the name of that device. Pedals that have some sort of binding mechanism that directly attaches to the base of the rider's shoe don't involve a toe-clip, and thus are "clipless".  I agree the word "clipless" is weird though, since the binding is another kind of clip, just not a "toe-clip".

Comment: There are actually at least six different “road” pedal styles and at least four different “mountain bike” pedal styles in the US that I can think of off-hand. Those appear to be the Look delta style, easily confused with SPD-SL and Look Keo.

Comment: If you go back as far as the 80's, there are probably another couple of dozen now defunct brands and models of clipless pedals, Although it looks like Look pedals, the OP could have a bike with now orphan pedals.

Comment: @mattnz A couple dozen in the 80s? Can you give some examples? Look and then Time are the only ones I recall from back then. Everyone else just licensed those designs and put their names on them. And the early Time style is the only one that has essentially disappeared.

Comment: 'Keystone' (bet you never heard of them) is one I used, but in the early days one man bands and hobbyists were milling out blocks of alloy or plastics and banging a pedal shaft onto them.  https://www.pinterest.co.uk/merlincyclesuk/history-of-clipless-pedals/  gives an idea of what has been tried.  (Keep in mind the 1980's and early 1990's was pre-internet, so there will be no record of many)

Comment: Downvoted because although you are correct that these are road pedals, you didn’t mention exactly which system/cleats these are.

Comment: If just flooding unnecessarily details and not answering the question was commonly considered worth downvote, stackexchange wouldn't have many high reputation users.

Comment: Perhaps this answerer was thinking 2 as in the 3 bolt vs 2 bolt shoe interface, which to my knowledge encompasses virtually all cleats for all systems, I'm not aware of others but they could exist for niche markets.

Comment: Nice to meet you all! Glad you’re here to give this asker the best advice you have.